# How to use a templatefield item within RowDataBound for GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

ASP.net:

```
...
<asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="7%" DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due" SortExpression="Due Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
...
```

C# code (in `RowDataDound` for `GridView`):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[4].Text)) //works correctly
{
    if (DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[4].Text).Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
    {
        e.Row.ForeColor = Color.FromName("#C00000");
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Task is Past Due";
    }
    else if (DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[4].Text).Date <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(inDateOffset).Date)
    {
        //e.Row.ForeColor = Color.FromName("#8A8C00");
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Task is at Risk";
    }
    else
    {
        e.Row.Cells[5].ToolTip = "Task is Not Due Yet";
    }
}
```

The above ASP.net/C# code worked correctly.

I had to modify the ASP.net to format the field to date:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="7%" HeaderText="Due" SortExpression="Due Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDue" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Due Date", "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Now the following line always returns a empty string: `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[4].Text))`

How can I modify the C# code so it is able to determine if the date is past due.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are now using an `<asp:TemplateField>`, you can no longer get the text the same way. You must find the actual label control. Instead of using `e.Row.Cells`, you'll use the label you bound the data to.

```
Label lblDue = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDue");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lblDue.Text))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `DateTime.Parse(lblDue.ToString()).Date < DateTime.Now.Date` is failing now.

Comment: You need the text of the label. You are doing `ToString()` on the label control. `lblDue.Text` instead of `lblDue.ToString()`.

Comment: Silly me. I wasn't thinking straight. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Comment: I +1 and accepted your answer for a quick and simple solution.